# resume/suspend enery star linux from command line

Tags: linux, acpi

I have an ssh connection to a linux machine which is hibernated after some non-activity time.

I want to make it resume, how do I do that?
(writing to /dev/mouse to simulate mouse movement didn't do the trick)

Comment: How can you still have a connection to a hibernated machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A machine that is hibernating cannot come out of sleep without pressing the power button, or sending a magic packet if the ethernet adaptor has Wake On Lan (WOL) capability and the motherboard supports that. WOL packets can only be generated on the local network, not remotely from other networks.

-Adam

Comment: but if I'm root on the machine - can't I simulate such activity?

Comment: In hibernate, the processor is HALTED, bus activity is stopped.  How do you expect to be able to execute any code regardless of your user privileges?  Are you sure the machine is hibernating, and not suspended?

Comment: I have an open ssh connection to the machine. I can execute programs.
it is definitively NOT halted

Comment: Then it cannot be in hibernate or suspend.  Exactly what do you mean when you say the computer is in "hibernate" mode?  How do you know it's in that mode?  What is the difference between "hibernate" and normal?

Comment: @Adam "WOL packets can only be generated on the local network" that statement is false. WOL packets can be routed to broadcast to all machines on the local network using UDP and come clever port forwarding.

Comment: @Evan - Typically if you want to be able to wake any machine on your network, you use subnet directed broadcasts.  However, SDB ability requires routers and switches that are specifically configured for this feature to work.  There are other ways to get a magic packet to another computer even if it's not on your network.  Those who want further details can find this and much more on the internet - wikipedia is as good a place to start as any: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN

Comment: @Adam I understand the concept of subnet broadcasting but it's still inherently unsecure. For instance if one were to send a smurf attack on that address it would only be forwarded to a subnet instead of the whole local net but that doesn't solve the issue. Would you add an entry into the ARP table to translate a specific incoming (and not well known) IP address to a broadcast, or would you forward it to a computer that can do DPI (Deep Packet Inspection) to verify the that the packet is a WOL and trigger the broadcast locally instead?

Comment: @Evan - It seems like we're going off track.  The OP is about waking up a sleeping computer, which I answered.  I gave notice that under normal network conditions, WOL packets typically only appear on the local network.  I purposefully didn't go into detail about how one might overcome that limitation, because it is beyond the scope of the question.  If you have further questions about network configurations that allow certain WOL usage, then you might consider posting them to serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Adam has stated, some motherboards support waking from various states when an interrupt is triggered.

The key here is which state you are referring to as hibernation; are you talking about an extremely low-power mode in hardware, or software hibernation where core memory is written to disk and the machine is turned off completely?  If the latter, WOL is the only possibility; if the former, than you can tell your motherboard to watch for interrupts from various sources and you can use some other means to trigger a wake-up.

A good starting point for reading [is the Wake-On-LAN article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_On_Lan).

Comment: 1. the timeout until hibernation is software-configurable, so that I assume it *does* have a possibility to do the same as root.
in addition, as I stated before - I do have an active ssh connection to the machine so it's no completely dead.

WOL is   disabled on that machine

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish WOL you need a few things:

First, check the BIOS of the machine you're waking to see if it supports WOL. If it does, make sure it's turned on.

Then get a program that can send WOL packets:

- In linux: sudo apt-get install wakeonlan
- For windows just find one to download using google. There are probably 100 different apps that do it, I don't use Windows so I don't have one to reference.

If you want to receive WOL packets from outside of your local network. Configure your router to forward port 9 to 255.255.255.255 (IP Broadcast-To-All address).

For some really useful info on the WOL protocol as well as a sample capture file that can be loaded in wireshark, [see this article](http://wiki.wireshark.org/WakeOnLAN).